# Extrair texto de coluna de uma tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo `metadata` está como tipo texto, mas eu acredito que na verdade é um JSON.

Quando faço:

```
SELECT metadata FROM  maxpay.mp_pay_orders;
```

O resultado é:

```
{"idtransactions":122882,"transação":122882}
```

Preciso extrair o `idtransactions` deste campo, de uma forma que eu consiga consultá-lo com um `IN`. Exemplo:

```
SELECT idtransactions from tabela1 where idtransactions in
    (select metadata??? from maxpay.mp_pay_orders)
```

A versão do MySQL do servidor é a 5.6. Pelas respostas, já vi que não é JSON, visto que só está disponível a partir da versão 5.7.8. Mas eu não consigo extrair essa informação desse texto de nenhuma forma.

Comment: Com qual linguagem você vai trabalhar? Digo isso pois cada linguagem tem sua forma de trabalhar com JSON.

Comment: Linguagem de banco de dados você fala? Porque preciso extrair isso dentro do banco, não na aplicação. MySQL

Comment: Linguagem de programação, tipo, PHP, Java, Python, C# e etc...

Comment: Como eu falei, meu problema não é na aplicação. Eu quero extrair uma informação do banco de dados, pelo próprio banco de dados. Eu nem sei qual a linguagem utilizada na aplicação.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu MySQL?

Comment: Minha versão é a 5.6, e acho que não posso alterar essa versão, pois é a mesma do servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir do MySQL 5.7.8 você pode usar as [colunas do tipo JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Aí você poderia usar uma das [funções disponíveis](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) para fazer seu `SELECT`, como a função [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) por exemplo:

```
SELECT
    *,
    JSON_EXTRACT('metadata', '$.idtransactions')
FROM maxpay.mp_pay_orders;
```

---

Caso seu servidor não suporte colunas JSON você pode utilizar uma [REGEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) para extrair uma informação da string. Ex.:

```
SELECT
    *,
    metadata REGEXP '"idtransactions":\\d+'
FROM maxpay.mp_pay_orders as po
INNER JOIN maxpay.transactions as t
    ON po.metadata REGEXP CONCAT('"idtransactions":', t.id, '\\D')
;
```

No exemplo acima o regex está sendo utilizado para fazer o `INNER JOIN` com a tabela `maxpay.transactions` utilizando o campo `idtransactions` de um JSON.

Eu utilizo o [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para criar uma regex para cada comparação feita com a tabela `transactions`. O `\\D` no fim é para que um `id` como  `123` não case também com `12300`. Dessa maneira limitamos apenas para o id exato

Comment: Quando tento executar, dá esse erro: `SQL Error [1305] [42000]: FUNCTION mm.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist`

Comment: MySQL 5.7.8 ou mais?

Comment: A versão do meu servidor é a 5.6.

Comment: Colunas JSON estão disponíveis apenas da versão 5.7.8 em diante, como mencionado na resposta.

Comment: Essa é a questão. Já consultei essas funções e tentei todas as que achei possivel, mas sempre dá esse erro de que a função não existe. Tentei atualizar o meu workbench para 8.0, mas como a versão do servidor é a 5.6, o mesmo erro sempre ocorre.

Comment: Eu entendi que só está disponivel a partir da versão 5.7.8, mas no caso da estrutura da tabela, eu preciso extrair essa informação. Tem alguma outra forma?

Comment: Vou atualizar a questão para usar REGEX mas é uma gambiarra e não é performático

Comment: Não tem problema, só preciso extrair essa informação de alguma forma. :)

Comment: Questão atualizada usando REGEXP no JOIN